# Unable to remove new line from the end of word in Perl

Tags: perl

I have the script as:

```
my $workItemCommentorURL = "https://almweb1.ipc.com/jts/users/sainis";
my $json_text= "curl -s -D - -k  -b ~/.jazzcookies -o commentor.json -H \"Accept: application/x-oslc-cm*\" \"$workItemCommentorURL\"";
my $content = `cat commentor.json`;
my $WICommentCreator = `cat commentor.json | perl -l -ne '/<j.0:name>(.*)<\\/j.0:name>/ and print \$1'`;
print "NAME OF COMMENTOR  ************-> \"$WICommentCreator\"\n";
```

This gives me the output as:

```
NAME OF COMMENTOR  ************-> "Shalini Saini
"
```

I.e Shalini Saini and followed by a new line.
Instead of

```
NAME OF COMMENTOR  ************-> "Shalini Saini"
```

Why there is a new line after Saini and why do the quotes come in the next line? How can I trim it?

Comment: Short answer: Remove the `-l` switch.

Comment: Only wondering. Why do you using `perl`, when in 5 line script you calling shell programs on 3 lines. Wouldn't be much easier using a simple `bash`? :) or, if you want use perl, simple make first an bash script with 3 commands (debug it) and call the script with one `qx()`...

Comment: Calling Perl from within a Perl program definitely seems... sub-optimal :-/

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: Remove the `-l` switch, because it causes `print` to have a newline at the end.

Long answer: Don't use a shell command to run Perl inside Perl, it's quite redundant. Just read the file normally.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $workItemCommentorURL = "https://almweb1.ipc.com/jts/users/sainis";
my $json_text= "curl -s -D - -k  -b ~/.jazzcookies -o commentor.json -H \"Accept: application/x-oslc-cm*\" \"$workItemCommentorURL\"";
my $content = do { 
    open my $fh, "<", "commentor.json" or die $!;
    local $/; <$fh>;
};
my ($WICommentCreator) = $content =~ /<j.0:name>(.*)<\/j.0:name>/;
print "NAME OF COMMENTOR  ************-> \"$WICommentCreator\"\n";
```